Modules with trivial duals
Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a right $R$-module, which is finitely-generated and non-zero. Will there always exist a non-zero right $R$-module map $\phi:M \to R$?. In other words will the dual always be non-trivial. Suppose we also assume that $M$ is a flat module?

What have you tried? Hint: $R = \mathbb{Z}$.

$R = \mathbb{Z}$ cannot work as all finitely generated flat modules over an integral domain are projective.

@schube It can work perfectly fine for the first part of the question.

Right, I was only thinking about the flat case. Apologies.

@BenSteffan: The only $\mathbb{Z}$-modules I can thing of are free ones, they always admit a non-zero module map to $\mathbb{Z}$.

@ZoltanFleishman If you cannot think of a single non-free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then you urgently should revisit the very basics of commutative algebra.

Oh my...

I hope this works:
Take $R = C(\mathbb{R})$ and set $M = R_{\mathfrak m_0}$, where $\mathfrak m_0 = \{f\in C(\mathbb{R})\colon f(0) = 0\}$. Being a localization, $M$ is a flat $R$-module.
Note that the canonical map $R\to R_{\mathfrak m_0}$ is surjective with kernel $I_0$, the ideal of all continuous functions vanishing in a neighborhood of $0$. Thus, $M\cong R/I_0$, i.e. $M$ is finitely generated.
Suppose $\varphi: M\to R$ is an $R$-linear map. For any $f\in\operatorname{im}(\varphi)\subseteq C(\mathbb{R})$, $f$ is annihilated by $I_0$, whence $f$ must be zero on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Due to continuity, $f = 0$. This shows that $\varphi = 0$.

Please don't answer no-effort and duplicate questions. See here for details.

@Martin The question doesn't seem to be a duplicate, because I did a quick search before answering. Neither is it no-effort, since the problem is well-posed, formatted, and interesting (at least to me). Of course, one could argue that the OP has not shown enough "work" but that's not easy to do, especially with these example-counterexample type questions.

It's clearly a PSQ and hence violates the site guidelines, as does your answer. Please check again the mentioned meta thread. And indeed it might be hard for the OP to show some progress here, but at least one could analyse some easy special cases, or explain where the problem comes from.
